# Output "none" - psycopg2 database query

Tags: sql, database, psycopg2

0

I'm new to SQL and currently try to resolve a data table problem.

I have a data [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mogc4.png) and now need to find firstly the dates, on which a request lead to an error. They are pulled as timestamps from the log database. Afterwards the status is checked where not status = '200 OK' and the days on which more than 1% of requests lead to an error are shown having count(*) > 0.01,order by num desc.

Now I have the problem, that I don't get any output shown:

OUTPUT IN THE TERMINAL:

--

Following the dates for >1 percent requests, leading to an error:
None

None

CODE:

def number_one_error():
    """
        Percentage of errors from requests
        Counting errors and timestamps
        Output:
            number one errors
    """
    db = psycopg2.connect(database=dbname)
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute('''

```
select  oneerror.date_column, round(((cast(oneerror.request_error as decimal))/requests*1.0),2) as percent
from (select date(log.time) AS date_column,
        count (*) as request_error
        from log where not status = '200 OK'
    group by date_column) as oneerror
join (select date(log.time) AS date_column,
        count(*) as requests
    from log
    group by date_column) as total
on oneerror.date_column = total.date_column
    where round((cast(oneerror.request_error as decimal)/requests*1.0),3)> 0.01
order by percent desc
          ''')
number_one_error = c.fetchall()
db.close()
```

THANK YOU SO MUCH!